# Custom Segment and Filter throwing Object reference error on Sitecore Experience Analytics

Tags: sitecore-commerce, experience-analytics

I created a custom filter and segment as shown below :-

[image]

Also I created a custom Segment as shown below :-

[image]

However when I add it in the core DB as shown below :-

[image]

I am getting this error instead of getting my custom Segment and Filter

[image]

Please suggest here.

Comment: any error from log files?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal

2928 12:50:01 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
18456 12:50:02 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.DimensionItems' (max size: unrestricted)
18456 12:50:02 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL https://commercesc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/Storefront/444FDFC97DE34755A583612B859F4AFB,DFF8BFA1EBB14B299DCA8CABDAC80AF3/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&&keyTop=10&keyOrderBy=count-Desc&dateFrom=02-06-2020&dateTo=08-09-2020&keyGrouping=by-key

Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.